# How do I tell trello to stop making a phrase a hyperlink?

Tags: markdown, trello

when I type something like `datamodels.tt` into a description or comment, it promotes it to a hyperlink on save. How can I force things that aren't truly domain references to not be hyperlinks? I don't see anything like it in the trello markdown docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
datamodels\.tt
```

In general, markdown sees `\` as a way to escape

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code back-tics in trello descriptions. I've tested it and it works. For example, `superuser.com` would not be linked.